# ModalBottomSheetLayout reappearance on navigation Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have some items in a modal sheet layout and when I press an Item, I navigate to another screen. However, when I press back button in the detail screen, the modal sheet reappears with a flashing behavior. I think this is because of recomposition but is there a way to prevent the recomposition without using a box and hiding-revealing the other screen? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I think this is because of recomposition" - re-composition happens a lot so its hard to guess, can you provide some reproducible code?, something that can be copy and pasted for us to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pop the bottom sheet from the backstack?

When navigating to your detail screen from the bottom sheet, get the instance of the `BottomSheetNavigator` you used to create the `ModalBottomSheetLayout` and do:

```kotlin
bottomSheetNavigator.popBackStack(backstackEntry, true)
```

You get the `backstackEntry` from the lambda when calling `bottomSheet(route)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I solved the problem by adding the necessary screens to another navgraph and opening it inside the modal sheet. However, what I wanted was making the modal sheet stay in expanded state when I navigate to another screen but as the previous screen re-composes on navigating back, the modal sheet were also opening itself again from hidden to expanded state. However, I still wonder if there are any solutions to prevent the recomposition of the model sheet or the previous screen in compose.